# I registered a user, but can not authenticate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, basic-authentication

I registered a user and he is present in database, however when i try to login through postman(email password) for some reason database can not find the user. Here are my security configs:

BookStoreSecurityConfig {
private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

```
    private final JWTTokenGeneratorFilter jwtTokenGeneratorFilter;
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestAttributeHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        requestAttributeHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");
        http.csrf((csrf)->csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                ).sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenGeneratorFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
```

Here are my application configs:

```
private final UsersRepository usersRepository;
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return username -> usersRepository.findByEmail(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("not found"));

    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception{
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
```

Here is my Authentication service:

```
@Override
    public AuthenticationDtoResponse authenticate(AuthenticationDtoRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate((
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        request.getEmail(),
                        request.getPassword())
                )
        );
        var user = usersRepository.findByEmail(request.getEmail()).orElseThrow();
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return AuthenticationDtoResponse.builder()
                .email(request.getEmail())
                .jwt(jwtToken)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: The where condition states `where email=?` while the translated query states `where user_id=?`

This seems like column mapping issue

Comment: where is that user_id mapping in entity?

Comment: The queries aren't the issue and you are looking at the wrong thing. Please add your security configuration and the error you get. You also might want to include the user registration code. Again the queries are not the issue.

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply, I am new here, I thought it will take at least a couple of days until the answer. I do not get an error. The problem is I registered a user(email and password), but when I login database can not find the user.

Comment: Here is my security configurations 
private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    private final JWTTokenGeneratorFilter jwtTokenGeneratorFilter;
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestAttributeHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        requestAttributeHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");
        http.csrf((csrf)->csrf.disable())
uthorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")

Comment: permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                ).sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenGeneratorFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();

Comment: Here is authenticaiton service
public AuthenticationDtoResponse authenticate(AuthenticationDtoRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate((
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        request.getEmail(),
                        request.getPassword())
                )
        );
        var user = usersRepository.findByEmail(request.getEmail()).orElseThrow();
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return AuthenticationDtoResponse.builder()

Comment: .email(request.getEmail())
                .jwt(jwtToken)
                .build();

Answer (score 0):

**this is not error**

```
    select
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.address,
        u1_0.created_at,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.password 
    from
        users u1_0 
    where
        u1_0.email=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        o1_0.user_id,
        o1_0.id,
        o1_0.address,
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.book_description,
        b1_0.genre,
        b1_0.language,
        b1_0.price,
        b1_0.publisher_id,
        b1_0.quantity,
        b1_0.title,
        o1_0.created_at,
        o2_0.id,
        b2_0.id,
        b2_0.book_description,
        b2_0.genre,
        b2_0.language,
        b2_0.price,
        b2_0.publisher_id,
        b2_0.quantity,
        b2_0.title,
        o2_0.price,
        o2_0.quantity 
    from
        orders o1_0 
    left join
        books b1_0 
            on b1_0.id=o1_0.book_id 
    left join
        order_details o2_0 
            on o1_0.id=o2_0.order_id 
    left join
        books b2_0 
            on b2_0.id=o2_0.book_id 
    where
        o1_0.user_id=?
```

this is hibernate logging what is happening behind the scenes telling you that it hit (user table selected a user successfully, and then orders, books, orderDetails, etc ...)
you can switch this log on/off using `spring.jpa.show-sql=true/false`

Comment: Thank you for answer. The problem is that when I register user(email,password) everything is fine, but when I try to login the same user database can not find one. I sended security configuration and authentication service in comments. If you have time can you please look through them. Thank you!!! I am new to spring and new to stack overflow.

Comment: sure I would love to help, comments are not good place for your code, update your question add securityConfigs, and other settings (userDetailsService, AuthController and AuthService, and any auth related class) to be able to help you